# String interpolation with the name of metric in the Datadog query

Tags: metrics, datadog

There are a bunch of custom metrics that looks like:

```
metric.name.key1
metric.name.key2
...
```

There is a template variables dropdown (https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/template_variables/) on the dashboard that contains all keys. (Name of the variable is *$key* and values key1, key2..)

The metrics query like this works fine:

```
avg:metric.name.key1{*}.as_count()
```

**But is it possible to parametrize the query with the *$key* variable by concatenation with the part of the name of metric?**
So it would look like this:

```
avg:metric.name.$key{*}.as_count()
```

As I know, it is possible to something like that by using tags but unfortunately, there are no any metrics with the tag "key".

Comment: did you find the answer?

Comment: @karthikeayan. As it turns out datalog queries don't support interpolation. So we had to introduce new metrics and use tags instead.